# Error using pool ( ) with imputed data when using mice in r

Tags: r, lm, imputation, r-mice

I'm quit new to R.

I would like to conduct a linear regression with my imputed data.

This is my imputation code (works fine):

```
imp <- mice(impu, predictorMatrix=pred, method=meth, m=10, seed = 1234)
imp$imp
imp_compl_all = complete(imp, "long")
```

I don't want to use the complete function, instead I want to work with all 10 imputations.

Therefore I use the pool ( ) function. However, the following error messages now appear, when using this code:

```
**# Fit linear model**
library(mice)

model1_coc_ger \<- with(imp_compl_all, lm(CocAmount \~ education, subset = Country == "Germany"))

pool.fit \<- pool(model1_coc_ger)

summary(pool.fit)
```

This error code occurs:

> pool.fit <- pool(model1_coc_ger)
> Error: No tidy method for objects of class qr
> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: In get.dfcom(object, dfcom) : Infinite sample size assumed.
> 2: 'tidy.numeric' is deprecated.
> See help("Deprecated")
> 3: 'tidy.numeric' is deprecated.
> See help("Deprecated")
> 4: 'tidy.numeric' is deprecated.
> See help("Deprecated")
> 5: 'tidy.numeric' is deprecated.
> See help("Deprecated")
> 6: 'tidy.numeric' is deprecated.
> See help("Deprecated")
> 7: 'tidy.numeric' is deprecated.
> See help("Deprecated")

For your information:
All my variables are numeric or factor variables. I have already tested this.
Of course, there are also missings in the imp_compl_all data set, as this is the data set with all imputations.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Looks like warnings to me rather than an error. Unfortunately, they have recently implemented some tidyverse stuff and can't seem to keep up with the pace at which tidyverse functions are deprecating. Which `packageVersion("mice")` have you loaded?

Comment: @jay.sf I don't get any outputs. I have the 3.16.0 version.

Comment: No clue why, make it [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/6574038).